# Place a div under specific div by ID

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML layout, in which the div with id=chart is below the div with id=infobox:

```
<div id="infobox"></div>
<div id="chart"></div>
```

In mobile version, I want to re-arrange them vice versa, i.e. infobox will be under chart:

```
<div id="chart"></div>
<div id="infobox"></div>
```

The only solution I could come up with is creating both layouts in different containers:

```
<div id="desktopContainer">
    <div id="infobox"></div>
    <div id="chart"></div>
</div>
<div id="mobileContainer">
    <div id="chart"></div>
    <div id="infobox"></div>
</div>
```

And in the CSS file, apply the following rules:

```css
@media ( max-width :768px) {
    #desktopContainer {
        display: none
    }
}

@media ( min-width :768px) {
    #mobileContainer {
        display: none
    }
}
```

However, these divs are actually very populated elements and this is creating a very dirty code. Is there a way to place a div under another div by specifying its ID, or a cleaner solution?

Note: It should work in IE9 as well.

Comment: At the first place, why do you wanna do this?

Comment: Because mobile device is small and the first thing to catch attention should be chart. However desktop is large and everything can be in logical order, since they both can catch the attention.

Comment: Use FlexBox and `order`. Simple.

Comment: You don't need that, because IE 9 is not used in any device right? And my solution works fine in IE 9 because, it uses the default thing. Code it using the desktop version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have only one `#container` that holds both the `<div>s`. You can actually use `FlexBox` and use the `order` property this way:

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
}

@media ( max-width :768px) {
  #container div:first-child {
    order: 2;
  }
}

@media ( min-width :768px) {
  #container div:first-child {
    order: 1;
  }
}
```

**[`order` property:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order)**

> The CSS `order` property specifies the order used to lay out flex items in their flex container. Elements are laid out in the ascending order of the order value. Elements with the same order value are laid out in the order in which they appear in the source code.

The above code is very generic, as it uses `#container` and `:first-child`, so you can tame it yourself according to your needs. Let me know if you need further help.

More information: [**A Complete Guide to Flexbox**](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) by CSS Tricks.

Comment: I tried this solution. In my question, I only showed two divs; infobox and chart. Bu there are 5 divs actually. And when I give order:2, the infobox is skipping all the divs and going to the bottom of the page.

Comment: @FarukYazıcı I specifically gave you a link to understand how `order` works. I understand that you have more divs. Ordering is just like ordering. The lowest comes first and highest value last. Hope you understood.

Comment: This is a good solution but I read that flexbox won't work in IE9. I'm updating my question accordingly.

Comment: @FarukYazıcı You don't need that, because IE 9 is not used in any device right? And my solution works fine in IE 9 because, it uses the default thing. Code it using the desktop version.

Comment: Even so, resizing the window would cause problem

Comment: @FarukYazıcı Use `respond.min.js` for IE 9 and below where responsiveness is not supported.